# Error in AutoCompleteText when the inputed text isnt on the autocomplete list for android

Tags: android, database, autocompletetextview

I'm using an AutoCompleteText for searching a location which would be connected to the database and the result would be shown. everything works fine when the inputed text is what is on the autocomplete list. But when i tried to input with a different text, which isnt available on the database, the application will get a force close. 
here is my code

```
DataSPBU helper = new DataSPBU(this);
database = helper.getWritableDatabase();

   Cursor dbCursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {SPBU, Alamat, JenisBensin, FasilitasUmum}, Alamat + "=?",new String[] {lokasi}, null, null, null);
    if(dbCursor.moveToPosition(0)) {
        String namaSpbu = dbCursor.getString(0);
        String alamatSpbu = dbCursor.getString(1);
        String jenisSpbu = dbCursor.getString(2);
        String fasilitasSpbu = dbCursor.getString(3);
        namaSpbuEdit.setText(namaSpbu);
        alamatEdit.setText(alamatSpbu);
        jenisBensinEdit.setText(jenisSpbu);
        fasilitasEdit.setText(fasilitasSpbu); 
    }
    else {
        notFoundDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("RESULT NOT FOUND")
        .setMessage("Hasil Tidak Ditemukan")
        .setNegativeButton("close", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
            }
        })
        .create();
        notFoundDialog.show();

    }
```

//

any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hey man when ever you enter a new text first enter into database after fetch the data,
then the application does not force close .and the data also shown in autocomplete text view
code::

```
String s=Edittext.getText().toString();

db.insert(s);
```

after bind the data with your resource